# What is the maximum of the number-format in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to know what is the maximum value the number-format?
For example int32 can handle 4.294.967.296 values.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Based on [this Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A81042_01/DOC/server.816/a76965/c10datyp.htm#743):

> The NUMBER datatype stores fixed and floating-point numbers. Numbers
> of virtually any magnitude can be stored and are guaranteed portable
> among different systems operating Oracle, up to 38 digits of
> precision.
>
> The following numbers can be stored in a NUMBER column:
>
> - Positive numbers in the range 1 x 10<sup>-130</sup> to 9.99..9 x 10<sup>125</sup> with up to 38 significant digits
> - Negative numbers from -1 x 10<sup>-130</sup> to 9.99..99 x
>   10<sup>125</sup> with up to 38 significant digits
> - Zero
> - Positive and negative infinity (generated only by importing from an Oracle Version 5 database)

[There's also this other documentation](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-datatypes.html) which summarizes very well the types and precision for numeric and other data types as well.